# laravel 5.4 Common data from the database for different uses

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pivot table where the user id and project id are located. I would like to draw all joint projects for 2 different users. How to do it? I am currently downloading all projects for a logged-in user, but I would also like to download projects for a logged-in user and for example a user with id 2. This is what i have now:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
$projects = $user->projects;
```

Comment: Try to read my suggestion, I went the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch the second user's projects with a condition:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
$projects = $user->projects;
$user2 = User::findOrFail(2);
$sharedProjects = $user2->projects()->whereIn('id', $projects->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Comment: I have question, can I do something like this in blade ? For example show all projects for user - {{ $user->projects}}  ??

Comment: @PatrykPrzybylski yes you can, ->with('user', $user) first then call it in view

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after reading your question carefully again, I would go the other way around.

I assume that you've a Project model and that you also set a users relationship in the model.

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query
      ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
      ->where('id', 2);
})->get();
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: You’ll never have a user where id=2 and id=1 so your subquery never hits @MyLibrary